# Rails: Select options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I asked a similar question about select options a while ago but I still can't seem to wrap my head around it. I'm rather new to rails but here's what I'm trying to do

> I have a Post table & in it, I have a "**post_status**" column. I
>   would like to give each post 3 options:
>
> 1. Draft
> 2. Pending
> 3. Publish

**How would I go about creating these 3 options in Rails?** *(I was advised not to use booleans for this)*

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on @Alexander Kobelev answer, I'd put it all in the model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS_OPTIONS = {
    :draft => 'Draft',
    :pending => 'Pending',
    :published => 'Published'
  }
  validates_inclusion_of :post_status, :in => STATUS_OPTIONS.keys
end
```

in your view:

Post Status: `<%= select(:post, :post_status, Post::STATUS_OPTIONS.invert) %>`

Comment: This is so much simpler. No need to generate another controller/model. Thank you @Cody

Answer (score 1):

In this particular instance they look like status flags that could be handled a few ways, but you've asked about select options so here's a solution for that method.

Because you don't specify if you need to keep the values already in the table I've detailed a method that allows you to keep them by converting them to IDs (assuming they are currently strings), if this is not relevant then follow only the bold instructions.

**Create a PostStatus resource** (model, migrate, controller/view if you need the ability to change them).

**Define the relationships**

```
PostStatus
  has_many :posts

Post
  belongs_to :post_status
```

**Add values to your PostStatus table** (if you have a live system with strings in the table you should match the existing post status strings here to allow you to convert the data (detailed below).

**Change column name to post_status_id in the Post table, change its type to int. If this isn't live then just redo the migrate with the column as integer.** If it is a live system you'll need to convert your data into a new column instead of just changing its type, the below is a suggested method.

```
add_column :posts, :post_status_id_tmp, :int

Post.reset_column_information # make the new column available to model methods
Post.all.each do |post|
  # Assuming you have a string with the option text currently:
  post.post_status_id_tmp = PostStatus.find_by_name(post.post_status).id
  post.save
end

remove_column :posts, :post_status
rename_column :posts, :post_status_tmp, :post_status_id
```

**In your post form add a selectbox.**

```
<%= form.collection_select :post_status_id, PostStatus.all, :id, :name %>
```

That should at the least get you started!

Comment: While this would work it requires another DB hit to get the status (in English terms for instance), or you'd have to eager load it during the fetch. Overall seems like more work for not much gain. Unless you wanted to dynamically manage Status options.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_inclusion_of :status, :in => [:draft, :pending, :publish]

 def status
   read_attribute(:status).to_sym
 end

 def status= (value)
   write_attribute(:status, value.to_s)
 end
end
```

where status is :string, limit: 20 (it's just for example) in migration

or you can try to use https://github.com/jeffp/enumerated_attribute

Comment: This one seems simpler & I'm beginning to wrap my head around it. What's the 'limit:20' doing? I'm testing it out right now btw to see if I can get it to work @Alexander

Comment: @Jon limit: 20 - max length of string. Look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column